# Error while starting lwc local server

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dev-server

[MODULE_NOT_FOUND] Error Plugin: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server: Cannot find module '@babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor' Require stack:

Answer (score 3):

This is solved now.

By going into this directory, mentioned in the log:
root:
/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/@salesforce/lwc-dev-server

I then deleted the node_modules folder and reinstalled the dependencies using:

```
npm install --save-dev
```

[I referenced this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/issues/98)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using:https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

1.run  'npm install -g node-gyp' in command prompt.

2.Install the current version of Python from the Microsoft Store package(I installed 3.10.8 from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3108/)
3.Install Visual C++ Build Environment: Visual Studio Build Tools (using "Visual C++ build tools" workload) or Visual Studio Community (using the "Desktop development with C++" workload)
4.Launch cmd, 'npm config set msvs_version 2017'
5.now try to run ' sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server'
Hope this helps